# Why doesn't this code appear to add record to Meteor.users.profile object?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to create a page to contain a profile form.  So I've got a text box for a 'name' field and a button to add it.

So in my client code I have:

```
  Template.profile.events({
     'click input.add': function () {
        Meteor.users.update({_id: this._id}, { $set:{"profile.name": profile_firstname}} )
     }
  });
```

and in my template I have:

```
<template name="profile">
{{#if currentUser}}
<div class="profile">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  <input type="text" id="profile_firstname" />
  <input type="button" class="add" value="Update Profile" />
</div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

When I try to find the users on the console I don't find the profile.  What else do I need to do get this working?

Comment: What errors show in the console when you trigger the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Meteor.userId()` rather than `this._id`.

```
Template.profile.events({
  'click input.add': function (e, t) {
    var firstname = t.$('#profile_firstname').val();
    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, { $set:{"profile.name": firstname}} );
  }
});
```

In the click handler, `this` refers to the data context of templates input element. Alternatively, you could also set the context using `#with` and your original code would work.

```
<template name="profile">
{{#if currentUser}}
<div class="profile">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  {{#with currentUser}}
  <input type="text" id="profile_firstname" />
  <input type="button" class="add" value="Update Profile" />
  {{/with}}
</div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: I tried using Meteor.userId() and when I try to add a name I get the error "too much recursion" line 394 of ejson.js

Comment: @user1532669 Just updated the event handler to get the value of the input from your template. `profile_firstname` is an element in the document which cannot be inserted.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.  I take it the params in the function, e & t are just the exception and template objects respectively, that correct?

Comment: The event, and the template instance.